# Macbook Pro with Yosemite very slow

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I've upgraded my mac from Mavericks to official Yosemite. In the first day my mac was normally, but in the second day, it was unusable, very slow and it was not responding, The third day(now) still like that. I dont know what to do, I've already reset pram, reset smc, repaired disk permissions, tried to reinstall Yosemite and nothing changed. I think it can be the file vault that I had activated when I upgraded to Yosemite, but I can't even know the percentage of the process. My MacbookPro is a version late 2011, processor i5 2.4Ghz, 16gb ram, 500gb HD. I would appreciate if somebody could help me.

Comment: I don't suppose you activated FileVault during installation? I found with my late 2011 MBP (500GB at the time) that FileVault was making my computer unusable. EDIT: follow [these](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2011/11/23/using-the-command-line-to-unlock-or-decrypt-your-filevault-2-encrypted-boot-drive/) instructions to disable it without having to re-install.

Comment: I activated FileVault after the installation. Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: Do you eventually use Little Snitch, CrashPlan or any other apps that reside in the menu bar?

Comment: The subtle cause and simple cure of my own MacBook Pro/Yosemite slowdown are detailed in the question "This “weird group trick” makes MacBook Pro login, apps, and systems run slow slow slow … but why?".  Url: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171862/this-weird-group-trick-makes-macbook-pro-login-apps-and-systems-run-slow-slo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the command in terminal to disable filevault, that is:

```
fdesetup status        # to check the status of file vault
sudo fdesetup disable  # to disable file vault
```

Comment: This does not actually allow me to turn off FileVault in system preferences. Do I need to restart it now on the backend and see if this corrected the freezing issues?

Comment: check  this link and do the same steps   http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/24/speed-up-os-x-yosemite-mac/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a common issue with Yosemite, see e.g. [a Mac Rumors thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1814416).

In the last couple of days there also popped up several articles complaining about Apple’s current state of its software. You can find a good overview of the most common issues in [this article](http://glog.glennf.com/blog/2015/1/6/the-software-and-services-apple-needs-to-fix) (it’s also worth to skim over the comments as there are issues that aren’t discussed in the article).